# Can't post textarea with newlines/carriage return on submit

Tags: php, html, textarea

I'm simply trying to pass the values in a textarea through the post variable (or whatever $_POST is).  More specifically I want to include the newline characters in it.

Whenever I hit submit I have my code re-direct me to another webpage.

```
<form action="blah.com" method="post">
```

....

```
   <textarea id="Field15" name="Field15" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit or Perish" class="submit_button"
```

When I'm redirected to the new page and I attempt to spit out the $_POST value to the console but i get:

SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

**This only happens when I input newline into the textarea field**

How can I pass the textarea text between pages?

Thanks for all your help.  And yes I've tried looking at similar posts, but please do direct me to one that could help.

Here is more of my code:

....

```
     <div class="form_field"><div>Major Accomplishments:</div>
       <textarea id="Field15" name="Field15" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
     </div>

     <div class="form_field"><div>Project Challenges/ Concerns:</div>
       <textarea id="Field16" name="Field16" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
     </div>

     <div class="form_field"><div>Next Steps:</div>
       <textarea id="Field17" name="Field17" cols="50" rows="10">
     </textarea><br/>
 </div>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit or Perish" class="submit_button" >
```

//I just include this to be used for other reasons but my goal is to pass the arguments to the new page using $_POST
     $('#Field1').change(function(){
       window.location.replace("http://physicianleadership.org/Leadership_Initiatives_Page.php?"+
                              "Field1="+document.forms['the_form']["Field1"].value);
     });

```
 </script>
```

Comment: Whats the Content of your process PHP File?

Comment: I have no idea how to add to the original post:

Comment: Click EDIT under the Tags under your Question

Comment: hahaha, wow I swear that wasn't there a minute ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpected EOF may occur due to various reasons such as missing parenthesis {, } or missing delimiters ?> or bad if else logic.

If everything mentioned above is done right,

It shouldn't be a problem to post a text area with new line unless you're using some ajax.

If you're pretty sure that the error has occurred only when there is a new line try to replace new line with space after you submit:

$_POST['Field15'] = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_POST['Field15']));

Comment: I think the OP wants the Line Breaks in the Code so I would rather replace with `\n` etc. or `<br/>` Tag

Comment: yep if you want a line break in code you can replace space with <br /> as j_s_stack sugessted

Comment: Yeah I'd prefer the newlines in the code.  Also, unless I can pass the $_POST to a function before the submission, I can't access the $_POST until the next page, and by that point thats where I experience that EOF issue

Comment: can you post your php file here?

Comment: *******Ok so user370..... was right**********.  I had to post what he said after the page was redirected.  Ok thanks a ton guys.  I was thinking I was supposed to add that before.

Comment: good to hear that helped you out!! can you please vote up my answer :)